# Getting an indexes item count with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing some code where we are inserting 200,000 items into an ElasticSearch index.

Whilst this works fine, when we get a count of items in the index to ascertain everything went in, we are not getting the same number.  However, if we wait a second or two, the count is correct.

Therefore, is there a programmatic way we can get a real count from ElasticSearch without having to `sleep` or similar?

Answer (score 7):

Newly indexed records become visible in search results only after the [Refresh](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-refresh.html) operation. Refresh is called automatically with frequency specified by [`index.refresh_interval`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings.html) setting, which is 1s by default. When writing elasticsearch tests, it's customary to call refresh after indexing to make sure that all indexed records are available in searches. However, excessive refresh calls (after each record, for example) in production code might hamper the elasticsearch indexing performance.